# Checkmarx report getting Recurring false postives

Tags: checkmarx

Salesforce complete org i have checked the details like security and Quality in this Checkmarx Report documentation showing Recurring false postives, if it is possible to remove recurring false positives. How can remove this

Comment: Not AFAIK https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213260/checkmarx-force-com-security-source-scanner-any-way-to-mark-known-false-positi.

Comment: @KeithC how can avoid Occurrence multiple time. one time showing which is fine but same thing will not show in Checkmarx report

Comment: Do you have your own instance of Checkmarx or are you using the Salesforce Scanner? If the former, you can customize Checkmarx to ignore the pattern its detecting. Its in the documentation on how to do this. Checkmarx is no different than PMD or other static code analyzers when it comes to finding these like this by using "rules".

Comment: @crmprogdev i am using http://checkmarx.iaglab.com/ url

Comment: Unless you're using a paid subscription, and it sounds as though you're not, you won't be able to customize the pattern detection modules.